# Pixelated HDMI output in kernel >5.19.0-38-generic

Tags: kernel, hdmi, antialiasing

After one of the recent updates on top of a standard 22.04.1 installation, booting into kernel newer than `5.19.0-38-generic` (e.g. `5.19.0-46-generic` as of today, I think I tried `.0-42` before as well) antialiasing is broken for the entire UI. It happens on an external HDMI screen, a screenshot doesn't exhibit this problem (as if it was antialiased). I looked through the release notes but found nothing obvious, changing stuff in Gnome Tweak Tools doesn't make it go away either. Could this be a bug? How do I diagnose this further?

Smooth (old kernel):
[image: Smooth (old kernel)]

Pixelated (new kernel):
[image: Pixelated (new kernel)]

---

Update: the machine is a Gigabyte Brix with a J3455 CPU, HD Graphics 500. The driver is i915, apparently.

Comment: You need to provide information on your GPU make and model and on the driver used, as this sounds like a graphic driver issue.

Comment: Go to the additional drivers tab in Software&Updates, and try changing the driver there

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi "no available drivers" after refresh

Comment: @Bruni the driver is "i915", it's a Gigabyte Brix with HD Graphics 500